# Edit the text location of a form

Tags: pages, css, forms, text

I was hoping someone might be able to help with something i imagine is very simple. I've created a form and added it to a page, however the text appears to be aligned to the left and the entry box to the center, leaving a large gap in between the two. How would i get the text to sit near to the entry box?(I've attached a screenshot as an example).

[image: form_page]

Comment: This is a css issue you're having. You would need to include the css rules for the affected form. You would need to know if the form is in a table it using div. Also if the left column is fine width, etc.

Comment: Share code that generated the form.

Answer (score -1):

Inspect the text in your browser by right clicking it and picking Inspect.  This should open up a window where you can adjust the CSS for all the elements on the page.  You will need to play around with what needs changed.

Once you figured out what needs to change, you can copy the new styles into the admin.  Go to `Admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`, paste your new styles in the textbox and publish the changes.